# How can i tune this mysql query to run successfully

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is my query on mysql version 8

```
select sender, fullName, phoneNumber, addressState, businessName, bvn, max(date)
from tranlog t INNER JOIN agent a on t.sender = a.realId 
where captureDate < '2022-03-01' and active = 'Y' and thirdparty = 0 
group by sender
```

```
CREATE TABLE `agent` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `realId` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addressState` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addressCity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `businessName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corporate` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `thirdparty` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`fee_group`),
  KEY `realId` (`realId`),
  KEY `agent_password` (`password`),
  KEY `agent_idx` (`active`,`thirdparty`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29784 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `tranlog` (                
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT                       
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL                          
  `captureDate` date DEFAULT NULL                               
  `sender` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL                         
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                
  KEY `tranlog_date` (`date`)                               
  KEY `sender` (`sender`)                           
  KEY `tranlog_capturedate_idx` (`captureDate`)                             
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49373312 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
```

[image]

But i keep getting 'C:windows\TEMP#sql1234_2' is full which i believe is about temporary table

I have increased the size of tmp_table_size and max_heap_size to 3G yet no reprieve, the error keeps poping up.
Any ideas on how to tune the query

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%p_table_size"; for our review.

Answer (score 1):

Add a 'LIMIT CLAUSE' to your query. It seems you have a very large result set.